# Freshly received InstanceID token from Google server is invalid

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

In my android app I receiving token and instantly print it out in logcat

```
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
token = instanceID.getToken(PROJECT_ID,
    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "token: " + token);
```

Logcat:

```
08-10 17:28:45.881  19473-19492/ru.ilimnet.neka.telnetapp E/IIDIntentService token: <longToken:StringWithSemicolon>
```

Copy it from logcat and try to send message over HTTP:

```
{
    "to": "<longToken:StringWithSemicolon>",
    "data": {
        "message": "test"
    }
}
```

Error ***InvalidRegistration***...
How this can be done?

Comment: `INVALID_REGISTRATION` means you have an invalid registration token in the `to` field of your send message HTTP request. You might want to check if you have a valid `Sender ID` in your `instanceID.getToken()` method, also you can reinstall your app to get a new registration token.

Answer (score 0):

"to" -> Stands for GCMPubSub topics e.g. "to" : "/topics/global"

Use "registration_ids": ["RegId", "another RegId if needed"]

:)

Your HTTP post body should be :-

{ **"registration_ids": "RegId"**, 
  "data": { "message": "test" } }

Please let me know , if worked :)